# How to return a struct defined in a shared library from WCF Services

Tags: c#, wcf, complextype

I have two WCF Data services that both have methods `GetPerformanceValues` . These methods should return an array of objects containing two `double` fields: `Datetime` and `Value`. I know I can define a ComplexType `DatetimeAndValue` in .edmx file and return the array of such objects. But I will have to define it in each service (which number might grow someday) - so this is obviously not a good idea.

I would personally prefer returning an array of `Tuple<double, double>`, but it's said to be impossible.

The other compromise I can think of is to define `DatetimeAndValue` struct in a library shared by all my services. What should I do to expose such a struct in my services?

Comment: Do you use a contract assembly or just service references on the client side?

Comment: At this moment the only consumer is browser. So I really don't need any special structs, i just need to transfer to my client an array of pairs ov values - that's why I sai I'd prefer using Tuple<>

Comment: First, I don't know why a `Tuple<,>` would not work. That said, just *use* your type from the library. There is nothing special you must do.

Comment: When I try to do so I get an exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Tuple``2[System.Double,System.Double]' of method 'System.Tuple``2[System.Double,System.Double] Test()'.`

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the edmx file. I don't know (or like) Entity Framework enough to be of help with that. Passing `Tuple` around WCF services is not a problem. It works fine without EF.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot anyway. Now I know that I should try to find a way to use `Tuple<>`

Comment: I don't know if it might be connected or not, but judging from the error, it seems that the fully qualified type is spelled wrong. Instead of System.Tuple``2.... it should be System.Tuple`2, only one ` character should be in the type name.

Comment: I'm sorry to have disoriented you, it indeed was like `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load metadata for return type 'System.Tuple\`2[System.Double,System.Double]' of method 'System.Tuple\`2[System.Double,System.Double] Test()'.`